# Can't see association bonus for Stack Apps when viewing profile from Stack Overflow or Meta

Tags: support, user-accounts, linked-accounts, association

I've got three accounts: Stack Overflow, Meta and Stack Apps. Once I received the 100 association bonus, all three accounts got it. But when I view my Stack Overflow and Meta profiles, they don't show those 100 points for the Stack Apps profile. Meanwhile if I go directly to the Stack Apps profile, the reputation is correct there.

The association bonus for Stack Overflow and Meta is visible in all three profiles.

So, what is the reason that it is not showing bonus reputation of the Stack Apps profile?

Answer (score 3):

It's just a caching issue. Just give it some time to update and propagate across all sites.

Comment: More than a week has already past. Is it a normal delay?

Comment: he got association bonus point on Aug 9, today it is Aug 17, so i am thinking, how much time it requires to update and propagate across all sites ?

Comment: I remember mine doing the same thing for well over a week, it eventually worked itself out though.

Comment: So, I'll be waiting..

Comment: @horgh There might be an issue we gotta look at here... please hold. (At least you got the bonus and your rep is correct in the first place. Call that an upside. :))

Comment: @AnnaLear I don't get upset much about it really:)) It's just a question worth to be asked for me

Comment: I've added another account to my profile. It also gained the association bonus, and it's visible everywhere. The issue with my StackApp account stays open only for StackOverflow and Meta...the new account shows my StackApp reputation correctly

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov Good to know, thanks. This looks like an issue on our end. I'll see if I can ping someone about it tomorrow.

Comment: @AnnaLear In the end it is solved. I've mentioned it only today. But I think that last week it wasn't. So was it a caching issue or smth else?

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov A combination of caching and some backend work, I believe.